# issues with parcelable extension: getting unmarshalling unknown type code exception

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

long story short, I have one `settlementItemeBase` class as my father and two children. I want to make the father class `parcelable` so as extension happens, my two child classes be `parcelable` as well. I don't exactly know what I'm doing right or wrong. I searched little bit but nothing helped me. 
here are my classes:

SettlementItemBase:

```
public class SettlementItemBase implements Parcelable{

public SettlementItemBase(){}

protected SettlementItemBase(Parcel in) {
}

public static final Creator<SettlementItemBase> CREATOR = new Creator<SettlementItemBase>() {
    @Override
    public SettlementItemBase createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SettlementItemBase(in);
    }

    @Override
    public SettlementItemBase[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SettlementItemBase[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
}
}
```

first child class:

```
public class FirstClass extends SettlementItemBase {
private int id;
private int cardId;
private String cardNumber;
private String expDate;
private String currency;
private String url;

public FirstClass(){
    id = 0;
    cardId = 0;
    cardNumber = "";
    expDate = "";
    currency = "";
    url = "";
}

protected FirstClass(Parcel in) {
    super(in);
    id = in.readInt();
    cardId = in.readInt();
    cardNumber = in.readString();
    expDate = in.readString();
    currency = in.readString();
    url = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeInt(cardId);
    dest.writeString(cardNumber);
    dest.writeString(expDate);
    dest.writeString(currency);
    dest.writeString(url);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getCardId() {
    return cardId;
}

public String getCardNumber() {
    return cardNumber;
}

public String getExpDate() {
    return expDate;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
}
```

second child class:

```
public class SecondClass extends SettlementItemBase{
private int id;
private String currency;
private String accountNumber;
private String ibanNumber;

public SecondClass(int id, String currency,
                       String accountNumber, String ibanNumber){
    this.id = id;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.ibanNumber = ibanNumber;
}

protected SecondClass(Parcel in){
    super(in);
    id = in.readInt();
    currency = in.readString();
    accountNumber = in.readString();
    ibanNumber = in.readString();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(currency);
    dest.writeString(accountNumber);
    dest.writeString(ibanNumber);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public String getIbanNumber() {
    return ibanNumber;
}
}
```

I'm passing and getting an ArrayList of both child class' items with intent `putParcelableArrayListExtra` and `getParcelableArrayListExtra` methods and get the following error:

```
Parcel android.os.Parcel@2d0fde33: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3276849 at offset 172
```

any help would be appreciated 3>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I'm posting this for those who may run into the same problem as me. 
the problem was solved after adding the `Creator` statement to the child classes. 
for one of the child classes it would be like:

```
public static final Creator<FirstClass> CREATOR = new Creator<FirstClass>() {
    @Override
    public FirstClass createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FirstClass(in);
    }

    @Override
    public FirstClass[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FirstClass[size];
    }
};
```

hope this helps. 3>